# for in and objects inside objects

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json response from an API which returns an object that contains objects

something like:

```
{Object}->{results}->{manyObjects}
```

when running this:

```
var list = data.results.list;

for(val in list){
    console.debug(typeof val);
}
```

the console returns strings instead of Object.

Could someone help me scan the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for in loop will return all of the property names of the list object.  You must reference these properties on the object to receive a handle to them.

```
var list = data.results.list;

for(val in list){
    console.debug(typeof list[val]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code `val` is just the *key* inside the object, **not** the value that key points to. Try this instead:

```
for(var val in list) {
    console.debug(typeof list[val]);
}
```

Though with that in mind you may want to rename `val` to something else.